# Bootstrap datetimepicker doesn't work on ipad

Tags: mobile

I use Bootstrap-datetimepicker in a apache cordova application.

```
   <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
        <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" readonly="readonly" />
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                   </span>
        </div>
     </div>
    <script>
        $(function () {
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            ignoreReadonly: true
          });
        });
    </script>
```

works perfectly on simulator but can't change date with picker on "ipad". The picker closes before changing date.